# magento 2 : Add new attribute button not showing in Product Attributes Grid

Tags: magento2, attributes, grid

In my Magento store Add new Attribute button  not showing when I go to stores>product>attribute grid open but no showing Add New Attribute button.

Answer (score 0):

please run the below command and check it.

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Actually I am asking about button not about attribute add new attribute button not showing so I am unable to add new Attribute